# How to setup a Google Wallet Mechant Account for In-App Purchaing outside the US?

Tags: android, payment-processing, merchant-account

I live in Barbados and I want to setup In-App purchasing but I need a Google Wallet Merchant Account, unfortunately Barbados isn't a supported country for merchant account setup, see link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?hl=en

If I live outside the US, how can I setup a Google Wallet Merchant Account?

I tried Payoneer but a Google representative told me that I can't use Payoneer because Google uses ACH payments where as Payoneer uses ACH Credit payments.

I want/need to implement In-App Purchaing in my Android app,what do I need to do?

Are there any payment solutions similar to PayPal and Payoneer that would allow me to setup a Google Merchant Wallet Account?

If there is anyone outside the US and there country is not on the supported list, that have successfully setup In-App purchasing, can you share what steps you took?

Comment: What did you do after all?

Comment: Still searching. I did find Stripe Atlas but it is in beta.

Comment: I have the same situation at the moment and I have research a few possible solutions. 1. you can open a bank account in one of your neighbors country which is supported by google wallet merchant. 2. you can use amazon app store to sell your apps on Android devices. 3. You can Implement third party payment systems such as paypal. 4. Depending on your apps functionality you can set up a web based app and have a user registration payment system through your website. If you have resolved this issue by now please share your experience and a solution too.

Comment: @ Niki I did 1, 2 and 3 of your solutions above.

Comment: @NikiGetsadze any updates on this guys. Badly need this solution.